# Dynamically Adjust Font Size in a Fixed-Width Container Using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a web project where I have a fixed-width container displaying a user's name. I want to dynamically adjust the font size within this container as the user types more characters to ensure the text doesn't overflow. Additionally, I need to consider the varying widths of different characters, especially the differences between uppercase and lowercase letters.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        #profileCard {
            width: 300px;
            height: 150px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #profileInfo {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 10px;
            height: 100%;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }

        #name {
            font-size: 16px; /* Set a default font size for the name */
            transition: font-size 0.2s ease-in-out;
        }

        #inputBox {
            width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="profileCard">
        <div id="profileInfo">
            <p id="name">John Doe</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <textarea id="inputBox" placeholder="Type something..." oninput="updateProfileInfo()"></textarea>

    <script>
        const inputBox = document.getElementById('inputBox');
        const profileName = document.getElementById('name');
        const profileInfo = document.getElementById('profileInfo');

        function updateProfileInfo() {
            const typedText = inputBox.value;
            profileName.textContent = typedText;
            adjustFontSize();
        }

        function adjustFontSize() {
            const containerWidth = profileInfo.clientWidth;
            const textWidth = getTextWidth(profileName.textContent, profileName.style.font);
            const availableSpace = containerWidth - 20; // Adjust for padding

            // Calculate the ideal font size based on the available space and text width
            const idealFontSize = Math.min(16, (availableSpace / textWidth) * 10);

            // Set the font size, ensuring it doesn't go below a minimum size
            profileName.style.fontSize = idealFontSize + 'px';
        }

        function getTextWidth(text, font) {
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.font = font;
            const width = context.measureText(text).width;
            return width;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```